# beginner with UIPickerVIew in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

Can UIPickerView be re sized? Will you please provide me some example code of creating UIPickerView programmatically in iPhone.or let me know the basics to start with it.

Thank You,

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've know, UIPickerView can't be resized. Try to look the UICatalog sample code in the apple developer site.

Comment: hey able to resize UIDatePicker .. Thanks